# use Search Box of a website to search items using Java

Tags: java, selenium

I wanted to know how can I use a search box in a website to search an item using a java program. I used Selenium but I didn't understand anything.
Can you give me some example code? thanks, giuggioloni

Comment: You could follow some getting started about the topic like: https://www.airpair.com/selenium/posts/selenium-tutorial-with-java or https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Getting-Started or start a google search https://www.google.nl/search?q=selenium+webdriver+chrome&oq=getting+started+selenium+java

Comment: Please Go through [ask]